# PHP server creating image with header() not displaying

Tags: php, image

I am trying to draw a circle. The below code is working in my test server. It shows a red circle. But when the file is hosted on another server, it is not working , but only an 'x' mark. GD library is enabled in the server.

```
<?php
$im=imagecreatetruecolor(100,100);
imagefilledrectangle($im,0,0,100,100, imagecolorallocate($im,255,255,255));
imageellipse($im,50,50,50,50, imagecolorallocate($im,0,0,0));
$border=imagecolorallocate($im,0,0,0);
$fill=imagecolorallocate($im,255,0,0);
imagefilltoborder($im, 50, 50,  $border, $fill ) ;
header('Content-type:image/png');
imagepng($im);
imagedestroy($im);
?>
```

What could be the reason?

Comment: Check your logs. Probably one of the functions outputs some data, making the header not being sent. Another solution could be to change to `content-type` to `text/plan` and open the image. It would show the plain data you are sending.

Comment: My server means on your LocalHost(XAMP, WAMP)?

Comment: Do you get any error messages?

Comment: check anything (text/html) output before `header()`

Comment: Same script is working in test server WAMP installed in my coomputer. But not in another server which is XAMPP